# Thruk Business Process data export into elastic stack

Tags: elasticsearch, monitoring, kpi, thruk

We have our business processes configured in thruk and I want to visualize these business processes with our elastic stack, kibana in detail.

I am searching for the possibility to export hourly, daily, etc. the status of the business processes and when they have changed to store that in a log file which I can sent to our elastic stack to create a dashboard.

What would be the best approach to achieve this? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this questions answered in another forum.

Please follow this [link](https://monitoring-portal.org/t/thruk-business-process-data-export-into-elastic-stack/4634) to see the answer.

ANSWER:

As business processes end up as normal services, you could fetch the livestatus data or use the json api.
Or starting with the next release, you could simply fetch all data via rest api like:

https://demo.thruk.org/thruk/r/thruk/bp 1 to fetch the business process data itself and
https://demo.thruk.org/thruk/r/services?_THRUK_BP_ID[ne]= 1 to fetch all services related
to business processes.